# How to return a struct from an imported DLL-function in MQL4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

Is there a way to return a struct from an imported function in MQL4, without having to pass it as a parameter and making a memcpy?

Answer (score 0):

Be cautious with any kind of DLL-interfacing, MQL4 Documentation states:

> **Passing Parameters**
> All parameters of simple types are passed by values unless it is explicitly indicated that they are passed by reference. When a string is passed, the address of the buffer of the copied string is passed; if a string is passed by reference, the address of the buffer of this string without copying it is passed to the function imported from DLL.
> **Structures** that contain *dynamic arrays[]*, *strings*, *classes*, other *complex structures*, as well as *static* or *dynamic* *arrays[]* of the *enum*erated objects, **can't be passed as a parameter to an imported function**.
> When passing an array to DLL, the address of the beginning of the data buffer is always passed (irrespective of the `AS_SERIES` flag). A function inside a DLL knows nothing about the `AS_SERIES` flag, the passed array is a static array of an undefined length; an additional parameter should be used for specifying the array size.

More glitches apply... Then how to make it work?

Maybe a straight, heterogeneous multi-party distributed processing, which communicates rather results than function calls, independent of all nightmares of maintaining just DLL-imported functions API changes, is a way safer way to go. Using this approach for the last few years and since than have no problems with ***New*-`MQL4.56789` `string`**-s that seized to remain `string`-s and silently started to become **`struct`**-s etc.

Worth to know about.

[Anyway, welcome and enjoy the Wild Worlds of MQL4 -- may enjoy to click and read other posts on issues in MQL4/DLL integration and/or signalling/messaging in MQL4 domains. **Feel free to ask more**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bmql4%5D)

Comment: yeah, they are talking about passing parameter, but nothing about get structures as return value... I'm aware of the caution to take about importing dll (I'm actually using wine and I execute the dll code natively thanks to WineLib to make use of unix socket as communication point...) I guess about returning struct there is no such features and have to copy the requests... fortunately, the overhead should not be that huge...

Comment: How about not relying on MQL4 side code-syntax constraints and using smart ZeroMQ multipart messages ( wrappers available for almost all recently used languages + mainstream legacies ) and enjoy the minimum efforts on decoding and parsing any other sort of struct-alike representation masking?

Comment: As of what I understand, Zmq is a portable messaging library, that is indeed interesting, but after having took a look to the code, it doesn't do much more than insure atomicity in the message etc. so in my case, it's "the easy part" that already works ;)